# Error running PostgreSQL Deployment in Kubernetes: "No such file or directory" for data directory

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubectl, nfs

I am trying to deploy a PostgreSQL database using Kubernetes and encountered an error related to the data directory. Below is my YAML configuration for the Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        type: deployment
        app: db
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: affinity-type
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - postgres
      tolerations:
        - key: "key"
          value: "database"
          operator: "Equal"
          effect: "NoSchedule"
      volumes:
        - name: db-nfs-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: db-nfs-pvc
        - name: init-volume
          configMap:
            name: db-init
        - name: db-hba-conf
          configMap:
            name: hba-init
        - name: db-postgresql-conf
          configMap:
            name: postgresql-conf-init
      containers:
        - name: db
          image: postgres:14-bullseye
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db
          volumeMounts:
            - name: db-nfs-pvc
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: pgdata
            - name: init-volume
              mountPath: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
            - name: db-postgresql-conf
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
              subPath: postgresql.conf
            - name: db-hba-conf
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
              subPath: pg_hba.conf
          command:
            - "postgres"
            - "-c"
            - "config_file=/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf"
            - "-c"
            - "hba_file=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf"
```

POSTGRESQL_ENV:

```
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
```

Issue:
Upon deploying the PostgreSQL database using the above configuration, the pod fails to start, and the logs show the following error:

```
postgres: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata": No such file or directory
Run initdb or pg_basebackup to initialize a PostgreSQL data directory.
```

kubectl describe pod:

```
0/11 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/11 nodes are available: 11 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

Additional Information:

- I have verified that the PersistentVolumeClaim db-nfs-pvc is bound and available.
- I have included the environment variables POSTGRES_USER, POSTGRES_PASSWORD, and PGDATA to specify the PostgreSQL user, password, and data directory path.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you tried to add the `pgdata` data to the mount path so that it reads `mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata' somilar to your other mounts?

Comment: @marcelh applied your suggestion and received new log:
2023-07-30 13:54:14.624 GMT [1] LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata/postgresql.auto.conf"
2023-07-30 13:54:14.625 UTC [1] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata" has wrong ownership
2023-07-30 13:54:14.625 UTC [1] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.

Comment: @EdBlack The fastest way for testing would probably to change the permissions of the folder on the NFS server to those of your container. For a sustainable solution you probably need an `initContainer` similar to [this](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/d8f76f660ef6e48f61657b73d1e705b314ff536a/bitnami/postgresql/templates/primary/statefulset.yaml#L126) or you directly use the Helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the bitnami postgresql helm chart, trying to deploy postgresql to kubernetes from scratch would not be a smart move.

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/postgresql

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).